# Repeating JavaScript generated images many times

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a project where I'm switching to generating user avatars from SVG's on the client side. One problem is the chat window where the avatar needs to be shown near each message, possibly hundreds or even thousands of times.

For server-side generated images, I can just use `<img src="" />` and be fairly ceirtain there won't be memory overhead to store each image with the same URL. Not sure what to do if I want to do it all on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have so far come up with these options:

- Create a canvas for each message and draw the avatar there. Obviously, this means storing each canvas in memory at all times, so not a good idea.
- Use `toDataURL` and `<img src="data:...">`. Not sure all (or any) browsers will optimize using the data url for multiple images and couldn't find any info on that.
- Convert said data url to a blob and use `<img src="blob:...">`. The most complex solution, but at least the browser will hopefully know it's the same blob and not keep copies in memory.

Still, maybe there is something more elegant and efficient.

EDIT: I ended up using the blob solution using [toBlob polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). It works really well and also uses compressed PNG instead of uncompressed canvas data. Hope someone some day finds this useful.